# NDepend - Query to Reduce Matrix

Tags: ndepend

I'm using NDepend to write a query to extract a subset of my assemblies and their dependent assemblies into a Dependency Matrix.

I would like to further reduce the size of the matrix to show only dependent assemblies that have a small or medium coupling (the ones that would be relatively easy to decouple)  Therefore I only want to show the assemblies that have < 20 method usages.

how do I update this query to show this?

```
let agentAssemblies =Assemblies.WithNameLike("Agent")
let assembliesUsedByAgents = Assemblies.ExceptThirdParty().UsedByAny(agentAssemblies)
from a in agentAssemblies.Union(assembliesUsedByAgents )
select a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refine the query this way:

```
let agentAssemblies = Assemblies.WithNameLike("Agent")
let assembliesUsedByAgents = Assemblies.ExceptThirdParty().UsedByAny(agentAssemblies)

from a in assembliesUsedByAgents 
let methodsUsedFromAgentAssemblies = a.ChildMethods.UsedByAny(agentAssemblies)
where methodsUsedFromAgentAssemblies.Count() < 20
let agentAssembliesMethodsUsingMe = agentAssemblies.ChildMethods().UsingAny(methodsUsedFromAgentAssemblies)
select new { 
   a, 
   methodsUsedFromAgentAssemblies , 
   agentAssembliesMethodsUsingMe 
}
```

From the code query result you can visualise both **methodsUsedFromAgentAssemblies** and **agentAssembliesMethodsUsingMe**...

[image: NDepend Dependency Query]

.. and by right clicking methods sets, you can export both sets to the Dependency Matrix to have a clear understanding of which method is calling which method.

[image: NDepend Dependency Matrix]